# Python for Google Sheets: write dataframes to different sheets in the same workbook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, google-api

Using the code below, I am able to write the dataframe `df1` to the default first sheet (starting at cell ‘B7’) of the Google Sheet workbook.
In the same file, how can I add a new sheet to write each of these data frames (`df2`, `df3`, …).

```
cell_range_insert= 'B7'
values = df1.to_json()
body = {'values': values}
response_date= service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range=cell_range_insert,
    body=dict(
        majorDimension= 'ROWS',
        values=df1.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
    )
).execute()
```

#### Auto re-size Columns and Rows width:

```
request_body = {
        'requests': [
            {
                'autoResizeDimensions': {
                    'dimensions': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id,
                        'dimension': 'COLUMNS',
                        'startIndex': 0,
                        'endIndex': 26
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'autoResizeDimensions': {
                    'dimensions': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id,
                        'dimension': 'ROWS',
                        'startIndex': 0,
                        'endIndex': 1000
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        body=request_body
    ).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you should specify the sheet you want in the `range` argument. For example, if your second sheet is called `"Sheet2"`, for `df2` you would need to change the `cell_range_insert` variable:

```py
cell_range_insert= 'Sheet2!B7",'
values = df2.to_json()
body = {'values': values}
response_date= service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range=cell_range_insert,
    body=dict(
        majorDimension= 'ROWS',
        values=df2.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
    )
).execute()
```

This will insert the values in cell `B7` in the second sheet.

### Create and update second sheet

If you want to create a new sheet, you can add this to you `requests_body` variable:

```py
sheet_id_2 = 2 # id that your second sheet will have

request_body = {
        'requests': [
            # creates a new Sheet with particular id and title
            {
                'addSheet': {
                    'properties': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id_2,
                        'title': "Sheet2",
                    }
                }
            },
            # Resizing for first sheet (sheet_id)
            {
                'autoResizeDimensions': {
                    'dimensions': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id,
                        'dimension': 'COLUMNS',
                        'startIndex': 0,
                        'endIndex': 26
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'autoResizeDimensions': {
                    'dimensions': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id,
                        'dimension': 'ROWS',
                        'startIndex': 0,
                        'endIndex': 1000
                    }
                }
            },
            # Resizing for second sheet (sheet_id_2)
            {
                'autoResizeDimensions': {
                    'dimensions': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id_2,
                        'dimension': 'COLUMNS',
                        'startIndex': 0,
                        'endIndex': 26
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'autoResizeDimensions': {
                    'dimensions': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id_2,
                        'dimension': 'ROWS',
                        'startIndex': 0,
                        'endIndex': 1000
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        body=request_body
    ).execute()
```

Just make sure that this part of the code goes before the part where you insert the values.

If you want to add an arbitrary number of sheets you will have to go with a loop and use `append` instead of hardcoding the `request_body` dict.

Comment: Hi @mtzd, thank you, I tried your suggestion but I get error `HttpError 400: Unable to parse range: Sheet2!B7` . Next, I manually created `Sheet2` in the Google Sheet and then the code works. **Questions:** (1). How do I create Sheet2 automatically? ... (2). I have code to auto-size the columns and rows after the data has been written. Now that I am writing data to a new sheet (ie... Sheet2), how do I modify the code to automatically implement the resizing on every new sheet I create? I have added the auto-resize code in the main body now. Please chime in.

Comment: Hey @Sinha I updated the answer to account for what you're asking!

Comment: Hi @mtzd, Thank you, your input answers my 2nd question. However, can you also shed light on my 1st question? I would like to create a new sheet (Sheet2) and then write to it's B7 cell (as your first code suggests). Presently, if I dont have Sheet2 already created in my Gsheet, I get `HttpError 400: Unable to parse range: Sheet2!B7`

Comment: @Sinha I included everything in `request_body`. The first element `{'addSheetRequest': {'properties': {'sheetId': sheet_id_2,'title': "Sheet2"}}}` is the one in charge of creating a new sheet. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried your revised code but I see this error: `raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400` and `"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "addSheetRequest" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field."` Please chime in if I need to update anything.

Comment: @Sinha sorry, the JSON field I wrote in the answer was not correct, it should be `addSheet` instead of `addSheetRequest`. I updated the answer with that.